# Inno Setup add an option to install conduit toolbar

Tags: inno-setup

I been looking online for toolbar option for inno setuo code or example but I can't find any I want to implement toolbar option to install when user install my app.

anyone have any example for that?

It's simple just to choose if they want to install or not and 2 more check box for homepage / search 
and install it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you further define what you mean by "ToolBar"?

Comment: @Robert Love www.conduit.com/legal/SoftwareInstallerIntegration.aspx  and here is a picture might explain it much better http://www.conduit.com/Images/WizardScreenShot/BundleMockup523.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inno has several ways to pull of what your asking for.   On of the simplest way's is to use the `[Components]` and/or `[Tasks]` section.    Both are well documented in the help file.

The basic usage is

```
[Components]
Name: "ToolBar"; Description: "Install ToolBar"; Types: full


[Files]
Source: "ToolBarFile1.ext'; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: ToolBar
Source: "ToolBarFile2.ext'; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: ToolBar
```

Another options is to uses Pascal Scripting and use `CreateInputOptionPage()` function call to create a custom page.   This is also documented in the help file.   Several examples of how to use this can be found in other questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Love the components is really easy and nice but I need a way to be able to check if the user has FireFox this way to know if to install IE toolbar or FF can it be done by Components or only createInputOptionPage?

Comment: thank you for the code it's useful for other projects i have too. I have good news found a code that was built in the same purpose I need it's full code just seems like a small issue with the way it's called can you check my new question? I think you will have no trouble to spot the issue. Please check it if you got the time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562901/inno-setup-calling-custom-page-error-initializewizard