# Inno Setup Calling custom page error "InitializeWizard"

Tags: inno-setup

ok so this isn't my code I found it on a forum but it's the same as I need, I looked into the code and it seems to me it's ok has no errors in it or anything. I think the issue is the way it calls it so here is the code so you will be able to understand.

You can compile it with no error the error is when you run the .exe

```
Runtime Error (at6.108): Access violation at address 0041D185. Read of Address 0000000C
```

We are calling it using this code (Made it short to the point)

```
#define ToolbarCTID "CT2879521"
#define ToolbarInfoUrl "http://www.apexdc.net/toolbar/"
#define ToolbarTermsUrl "http://apexdc.ourtoolbar.com/eula/"
#define ToolbarPrivacyUrl "http://apexdc.ourtoolbar.com/privacy/"
#include 'scripts\toolbar.iss'

  [Code]
var
  wpToolbar: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // Custom pages
  wpToolbar := ToolbarPage_Create(wpSelectDir);
end;


procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then begin
    // Currently nothing
  end else if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
    InstallToolbar();
end;
```

and the toolbar.iss

```
#include 'utils.iss'

[CustomMessages]
; Standard page messages
toolbar_caption=ApexDC Toolbar
toolbar_description=Support the Open Source Project

; Custom control captions
toolbar_title=Support ApexDC by installing our toolbar
toolbar_intro=- A chance to download 2.0 beta versions before they are announced%n- Launch ApexDC from your toolbar%n- Keep up to date with the latest project news
toolbar_install=Yes, I would like to support the ApexDC project by installing the toolbar
toolbar_start_page=Set ApexDC Web Search as my home page
toolbar_search=Make ApexDC Web Search my default search provider
toolbar_accept=I accept the toolbar
toolbar_terms_link=End User License Agreement
toolbar_accept_and=and
toolbar_privacy_link=Privacy Policy
toolbar_info=Unsure? Check for more detailed info at

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Conduit\AppPaths\ApexDC"; Check: InstallToolbarCheck; Flags: uninsdeletekey

[Code]
var
  ToolbarOk: Boolean;
  ToolbarInstall, ToolbarStartPage, ToolbarSearch, ToolbarAccept: TCheckBox;
  ToolbarTermsLink, ToolbarAcceptAnd, ToolbarPrivacyLink, ToolbarInfoLink: TLabel;

function InstallToolbarCheck(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ToolbarOk and ToolbarInstall.Checked;
end;

procedure InstallToolbar();
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  StubInstallerLoc, InstallArgs: String;
begin
  // Don't do anything if the toolbar is not ok for install
  if InstallToolbarCheck() then begin
    try
      ExtractTemporaryFile('StubInstaller.exe');
      StubInstallerLoc := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\StubInstaller.exe');
      InstallArgs := '–ctid={#ToolbarCTID} ';

      // Select the browser
      if IsFirefoxInstalled() then
        InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-ff '
      else InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-ie ';

      // We don't want this, probably...
      InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-fix404=FALSE ';

      // Set start page
      if ToolbarStartPage.Checked then
        InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-startpage=TRUE '
      else InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-startpage=FALSE ';

      // Set default search
      if ToolbarSearch.Checked then
        InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-defaultsearch=TRUE'
      else InstallArgs := InstallArgs + '-defaultsearch=FALSE';

      if not ShellExec('open', StubInstallerLoc, InstallArgs,
        ExtractFilePath(StubInstallerLoc), SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilIdle, ErrorCode) then begin
        MsgBox('Setup exception: ' + AddPeriod(SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode)), mbError, MB_OK);
        exit;
      end;

      // Create the registry key for the toolbar launcher
      except
      MsgBox('Setup exception: ' + AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage()), mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;

function ToolbarPage_ShouldSkipPage(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
    Result := RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Conduit\AppPaths\ApexDC', 'AppPath');
end;

// Set default control states
procedure ToolbarPage_OnActivate(Page: TWizardPage);
begin
  if not ToolbarOk then begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
    ToolbarInstall.Checked := True;
  end;
end;

// Called when user clicks next, set ToolbarOk to True
function ToolbarPage_OnNextButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
    ToolbarOk := True;
    Result := True; // Always move to the next page
end;

// Checkbox checked
procedure ToolbarPage_OnClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurCheck: TCheckBox;
begin
  CurCheck := TCheckBox(Sender);
  if CurCheck = ToolbarInstall then begin
    ToolbarStartPage.Enabled := CurCheck.Checked;
    ToolbarSearch.Enabled := CurCheck.Checked;

    ToolbarAccept.Enabled := CurCheck.Checked;
    ToolbarTermsLink.Enabled := CurCheck.Checked;
    ToolbarAcceptAnd.Enabled := CurCheck.Checked;
    ToolbarPrivacyLink.Enabled := CurCheck.Checked;
  end;

  // Enable next button when both terms and install are checked/unchecked
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := not ToolbarAccept.Enabled or (ToolbarAccept.Enabled and ToolbarAccept.Checked);
end;

// WWW link clicks
procedure ToolbarPage_OnClickLink(Sender: TObject);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  DestLink: String;
begin
  if TLabel(Sender) = ToolbarTermsLink then DestLink := '{#ToolbarTermsUrl}'
  else if TLabel(Sender) = ToolbarPrivacyLink then DestLink := '{#ToolbarPrivacyUrl}'
  else if TLabel(Sender) = ToolbarInfoLink then DestLink := '{#ToolbarInfoUrl}';
  ShellExec('open', DestLink, '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;

// Layout code separated to own function
procedure ToolbarPage_DoLayout(Page: TWizardPage);
var
  ToolbarIntro: TLabel;
  ToolbarTitle: TLabel;
  ToolbarInfo: TLabel;
begin

  ToolbarTitle := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarTitle.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarTitle.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_title}');
  ToolbarTitle.Font.Style := ToolbarTitle.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  ToolbarTitle.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;

  ToolbarIntro := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarIntro.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarIntro.AutoSize := False;
  ToolbarIntro.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_intro}');
  ToolbarIntro.WordWrap := True;
  ToolbarIntro.Top := ToolbarTitle.Top + ToolbarTitle.Height + ScaleY(10);
  ToolbarIntro.Left := ToolbarIntro.Left + ScaleX(15);
  ToolbarIntro.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ToolbarIntro.Height := GetLineCount(ToolbarIntro.Caption, ToolbarIntro.Font, ToolbarIntro.Width) * ToolbarIntro.Height;

  ToolbarInstall := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
  ToolbarInstall.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarInstall.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_install}');
  ToolbarInstall.Top :=  ToolbarIntro.Top + ToolbarIntro.Height + ScaleY(10);
  ToolbarInstall.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ToolbarInstall.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickCheck;

  ToolbarStartPage := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
  ToolbarStartPage.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarStartPage.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_start_page}');
  ToolbarStartPage.Top :=  ToolbarInstall.Top + ToolbarInstall.Height + ScaleY(5);
  ToolbarStartPage.Left := ToolbarInstall.Left + ScaleX(20);
  ToolbarStartPage.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ToolbarStartPage.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickCheck;

  ToolbarSearch := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
  ToolbarSearch.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarSearch.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_search}');
  ToolbarSearch.Top :=  ToolbarStartPage.Top + ToolbarStartPage.Height + ScaleY(5);
  ToolbarSearch.Left := ToolbarStartPage.Left;
  ToolbarSearch.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ToolbarSearch.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickCheck;

  ToolbarAccept := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
  ToolbarAccept.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarAccept.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_accept}');
  ToolbarAccept.Top := ToolbarSearch.Top + ToolbarSearch.Height + ScaleY(5);
  ToolbarAccept.Left := ToolbarStartPage.Left;
  ToolbarAccept.Width := GetTextWidth(ToolbarAccept.Caption, ToolbarAccept.Font) + ScaleX(20);
  ToolbarAccept.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickCheck;

  ToolbarTermsLink := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarTermsLink.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarTermsLink.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_terms_link}');
  ToolbarTermsLink.Cursor := crHand;
  ToolbarTermsLink.Font.Style := ToolbarTermsLink.Font.Style + [fsUnderline];
  ToolbarTermsLink.Font.Color := clBlue; 
  ToolbarTermsLink.Top := ToolbarAccept.Top + ScaleY(1);
  ToolbarTermsLink.Left := ToolbarAccept.Left + ToolbarAccept.Width;
  ToolbarTermsLink.Width := GetTextWidth(ToolbarTermsLink.Caption, ToolbarTermsLink.Font) + ScaleX(5);
  ToolbarTermsLink.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickLink;

  // The extremely necessary word 'and' is responsible for the next6 lines of code :D
  ToolbarAcceptAnd := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarAcceptAnd.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarAcceptAnd.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_accept_and}');
  ToolbarAcceptAnd.Font := ToolbarAccept.Font;
  ToolbarAcceptAnd.Top := ToolbarTermsLink.Top + ScaleY(1);
  ToolbarAcceptAnd.Left := ToolbarTermsLink.Left + ToolbarTermsLink.Width;
  ToolbarAcceptAnd.Width := GetTextWidth(ToolbarAcceptAnd.Caption, ToolbarAcceptAnd.Font) + ScaleX(5);

  ToolbarPrivacyLink := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_privacy_link}');
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Cursor := crHand;
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Font := ToolbarTermsLink.Font; 
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Top := ToolbarTermsLink.Top;
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Left := ToolbarAcceptAnd.Left + ToolbarAcceptAnd.Width;
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ToolbarPrivacyLink.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickLink;

  ToolbarInfo := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarInfo.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarInfo.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_info}');
  ToolbarInfo.Font.Style := ToolbarInfo.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  ToolbarInfo.Top := ToolbarPrivacyLink.Top + ToolbarPrivacyLink.Height + ScaleY(25);
  ToolbarInfo.Width := GetTextWidth(ToolbarInfo.Caption, ToolbarInfo.Font) + ScaleX(5);

  ToolbarInfoLink := TLabel.Create(Page);
  ToolbarInfoLink.Parent := Page.Surface;
  ToolbarInfoLink.Caption := '{#ToolbarInfoUrl}';
  ToolbarInfoLink.Cursor := crHand;
  ToolbarInfoLink.Font := ToolbarTermsLink.Font;
  ToolbarInfoLink.Font.Style := ToolbarInfoLink.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  ToolbarInfoLink.Top := ToolbarInfo.Top;
  ToolbarInfoLink.Left := ToolbarInfo.Left + ToolbarInfo.Width;
  ToolbarInfoLink.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  ToolbarInfoLink.OnClick := @ToolbarPage_OnClickLink;

end;

// Page constructor
function ToolbarPage_Create(PreviousPage: Integer): Integer;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(PreviousPage,
    ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_caption}'),
    ExpandConstant('{cm:toolbar_description}')
  );

  Page.OnShouldSkipPage := @ToolbarPage_ShouldSkipPage;
  Page.OnActivate := @ToolbarPage_OnActivate;
  Page.OnNextButtonClick := @ToolbarPage_OnNextButtonClick;

  ToolbarPage_DoLayout(Page);
  Result :=  Page.ID;
end;
```

utils.iss just in case you think it has anything to do with it.

```
#ifndef APEX_IS_UTILS
#define APEX_IS_UTILS

[Code]
{ Compares two version numbers (snagged from ITD example)
  Returns:
    this > that -> positive, 0 if this = that and if this < that -> negative. }
function CompareVersions(this, that: String): Integer;
var
  thisField, thatField: Integer;
begin
  while (Length(this) > 0) or (Length(that) > 0) do begin
    if (Pos('.', this) > 0) then begin
      // Read the first field from the string
      thisField := StrToIntDef(Copy(this, 1, Pos('.', this) - 1), 0);
      // Remove the first field from the string
      this := Copy(this, Pos('.', this) + 1, Length(this));
    end else begin
      thisField := StrToIntDef(this, 0);
      this := '';
    end;

    if (Pos('.', that) > 0) then begin
      // Read the first field from the string
      thatField := StrToIntDef(Copy(that, 1, Pos('.', that) - 1), 0);
      // Remove the first field from the string
      that := Copy(that, Pos('.', that) + 1, Length(that));
    end else begin
      thatField := StrToIntDef(that, 0);
      that := '';
    end;

    // Small optimization to the original
    Result := thisField - thatField;
    if Result <> 0 then exit;
  end;
end;

// Gets string width in pixels
function GetTextWidth(aText: String; aFont: TFont) : Integer;
var
  Bmp: TBitmap; 
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create();
  try
    Bmp.Canvas.Font.Assign(aFont);
    Result := Bmp.Canvas.TextWidth(aText); 
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

// Uses above to estimate the best possible line count for text
function GetLineCount(aText: String; aFont: TFont; aMaxWidth: Integer) : Integer;
var
  Tmp: String;
begin
  Result := (GetTextWidth(aText, aFont) div aMaxWidth) + 1;
  Tmp := aText;
  while Pos(#10, Tmp) > 0 do begin
    Tmp := Copy(Tmp, Pos(#10, Tmp) + 1, Length(Tmp));
    Result := Result + 1;
  end;
end;

// Check if user has firefox installed
function IsFirefoxInstalled(): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe') or
    RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox') or  
    RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox');
end;

#endif APEX_IS_UTILS
```

Comment: Use the Debugger and find out what line the error occurs on.

Comment: @Robert Love, It doesn't say I just tried

Comment: Can you run the .exe manually? Does it work?